# Paired Differences T-tests for Odd number of Observations

Tags: repeated-measures, t-test

Suppose we have $m$ baseline data points and $n$ post-baseline data points where $m < n$. This is for one subject. Is it possible to perform a paired t-test on this data even though $m+n$ is odd? Can we thrown away the data that is not paired and perform the test?

For example, suppose the baseline data is $(1,2,3)$ and the post-baseline data is $(6,7,8,9,10)$ for one subject. Then we can form the pairs $(1,6)$, $(2,7)$ and $(3,8)$. The $9$ and $10$ would be thrown out. I guess if $m$ is not much greater than $n$, then we can still perform a paired t-test without a loss of power? Or perhaps do some data imputation?

Comment: In any *paired* test, the data already have a natural, given association, which is not present here. Because of that given association, it is obvious that $m=n$, so the situation you hypothesize never happens. You seem to have a [tag:repeated-measures] dataset: follow the tag links for more information.

Comment: @whuber: The data I have has a natural association. It is just that more post-baseline measurements were made. For example, $10$ weight readings were made on Bob before a diet and $20$ weight readings were made on Bob after a diet.

Comment: It is a correspondence but not a pairing. It would be a mistake to try to shoehorn it into a paired framework.  Please follow the tag links for more information.

Comment: @whuber: I see. A rANOVA (repeated measures ANOVA) seems appropriate to use.

Comment: Following from the weight example - are the repeat measures at baseline (or followup) supposed to measure the same thing, with differences between measures reflecting only random error? Given baseline or followup, does the order of the repeat measures matter?  More detail in the question on exactly what you have measured and what question you are trying to answer would be helpful.

Comment: @DLDahly: The repeated measures at baseline (or follow up) measure the same thing. The idea is to see whether weight changes significantly after the diet. There wouldn't be any carryover effects since the basic measuring procedure is as follows: measure before exposure and measure after exposure.

Comment: Sorry...1 more clarification. If you have 3 weight measures on Bob,  what is the rough time scale that these are measured across, e.g. 3 measures in 3 minutes, or 3 measures in 3 months?

Comment: @DLDahly: 3 measures in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Given your comments to help clarify the problem -

Let's say you measure Bob's weight at baseline 3 times, about a minute apart each. We can call these measures 1a 1b and 1c. Then you do something to him and measure his weight again a month later. Call these measures 2a 2b 2c. You seem to be trying to match 1a with 2a, 1b with 2b, 1c with 2c, and so on. The problem is that there is no reason to match 1a with 2a. In this case, 1a, 1b and 1c are all expected to be the same, except for small differences due to measurement error. It's no more logical to match 1a with 2a than it is to match 1a with 2b or 2c.

Assuming the error in your measures is very small relative to the scale of the thing you are measuring (i.e. using a digital scale to measure weight in adult humans) the easiest, but not the most "correct", thing to do is just to calculate Bob's mean weight at baseline and follow-up using the respective repeated measures.

A mixed model (or random effects model, multilevel model, hierarchical linear model) is the most correct thing to do, with your treatment included as a fixed effect. This will properly account for the within and between person variation in your sample.